# Product of 2 little oh function

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Good day, I wanted to ask about some properties of the little oh notation (or I guess properties of functions that are little oh)

If $f=o(h)$ and $g=o(h)$ then is it true that $fg=o(h)$?

Comment: No. Take $ f=n^\frac{1}{2} $ and $g=n^\frac{3}{5}$ both $f,g=o(n)$ but it is not the case with $fg$

Comment: Is $n^\frac{1}{2}=o(n)$? The way our lecturer defined it was the reverse of how you defined it it seems. As in, if $f=o(h)$ this means that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=0$

Comment: was I wrong? I remember that o notation ma'am strict upper bound.

Comment: A word version of little oh, at least the way we were presented it, was that $f(h)$ tends towards $0$ faster than $h$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clear that you are taking the limit as $h \to 0$, not as $h \to \infty$.  Once you say that, it is true because (for small enough $h$) you have $f(h)\lt h, g(h)\lt h,$ so $f(h)g(h) \lt h^2 \lt h$